# What is the time correspondence between PHP and Apache logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Say I have this PHP error log:

```
$ cat php_logs
[20-Sep-2019 03:05:03 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2621464 bytes) in /www/hello.php on line 1194
```

And these Apache access logs:

```
$ cat access_logs
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:04:12 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 7633
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:04:15 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9331
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:04:26 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9448
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:04:32 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 7128
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:04:52 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9453
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:05:01 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9795
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:05:00 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 10642
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:05:39 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9103
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:05:41 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 6470
10.1.2.3 - - [20/Sep/2019:03:05:40 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 8139
```

How can I understand which is the access logs related to the error shown? I am trying to understand which request caused the error. Can this be determined or is there no way?
I've tested that these fatal errors comes up as 200 status codes so, could it theoretically be any of the logs before `03:05:03` till `03:05:03-max_execution_time` ?

Thanks

Comment: Relying on timestamps will always entail a part of vagueness. You should rely instead of some unique ID per request for both your Apache and PHP logfiles. Also Apache has 2 logfiles by default, access_log and error_log, you should also look at that second one. If PHP created a fatal error it is most probably that the result for the client is not a "200 OK" code a,d maybe not even a reply at all.